# Permission denied when saving an image in android

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I can't save an image file, even after I request the permission.
I added the permission to the manifest file like this:

```
permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

But I keep seeing this error:

> Permission denied

Here is the relevant code:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void saveImage() {
    if (requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        showLoading("Saving...");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + ""
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            SaveSettings saveSettings = new SaveSettings.Builder()
                    .setClearViewsEnabled(true)
                    .setTransparencyEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            mPhotoEditor.saveAsFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), saveSettings, new PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String imagePath) {
                    hideLoading();
                    showSnackbar("Image Saved Successfully");
                    mSaveImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
                    mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageURI(mSaveImageUri);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    hideLoading();
                    showSnackbar("Failed to save Image");
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            hideLoading();
            showSnackbar(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error log:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@faa5b66[EditImageActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@63d69b7 TM=true MM=false
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
```

Comment: What Android version are you running on?

Comment: @Andrew  on android  9 and 10

Answer (score 2):

On Android 9 you need to request runtime permission which I think you are not doing correctly (See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

And on Android 10 file paths outside of your App's private directories are worthless.

Going forward it is probably best just to use Media Store or Storage Access Framework

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared

Media Store is probably better in your case. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is consecuence of how the permissions in Android Q has changed:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped